# idle session time out in hybris not working in other environment

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to set idle session time out in Hybris. Which i added the configuration in local.properties file. Its working fine in local ( keeping my site idle for some time and when i click again the user gets logged out).

The same configuration is also available in other environment(Dev,ITG) which is not working.

Code:

## Idle Time Out

default.session.timeout=3600
Thanks !

Comment: Did you check parameter is correct in hac?

Comment: yes, the value is there in HAC. with time what i mentioned.

Comment: Do you have any load balancer in production? May be it has own config.

Comment: Hi, I guess No. And in all other environment also, we have configured the same as shown below ,
default.session.timeout=3600